# SalesForce Vs Hadoop which is better?

Tags: hadoop, salesforce

I am having 4 years of experience in .net I would like to learn new technology, what could be best for me learning Hadoop or SalesForce?

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer to this question.  Hadoop and SalesForce are completely different technologies.  Hadoop is distributed storage and processing that is great for big data.  SalesForce is a cloud based CRM tool.

The question to ask yourself, is what do you want next?  Are you looking for a steady job?  Are you looking for a career in a specific field where one of these technologies would be more helpful?  What do you want?